# How to force an object into the render border?

Tags: rendering

I made a glass smashed by a bullet animation, with smoke simulation. I have 100 frames in the simulation but wish to render only one frame no. 61, where the smoke cloud is the most beautiful. Unfortunately, the bullet and a few other nice shards are already outside the render border, and they must be part of the rendering. I move them into the border but when rendering, they jump back to their previous place. How can I force them to be part of the rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your smoke animation is baked.

Go to your selected frame and delete all keyframes from the objects animation. Afterwards, you will be able to move your object freely.

(This will obviously delete the animation, so only do this if you are sure that you don't need it anymore.)

Comment: Tom, thank you for your kind help. On top of the keyframes, I deleted also the rigid body physics.